# Slicing a Column and Making Several Columns of Those Slices in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I want to create a new dataframe that has model response of each model in its dedicated column:

[image]

I can do`df.groupby('Model')['Model_Response']` to have the `Model_Response` series that is indexed by `Model` but then how to slice them bassed on Model and cascade them with `GroundTruth`?